# Console based torrent client supporting magnet link?

Tags: bittorrent

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme

OS: OpenBSD/Linux. Are there any torrent clients that support magnet links? It's an important thing that they need to be console-based only!

Comment: Good question. I stumbled upon thepiratebay.org the other day and to my suprise there was only magnet links for all torrents. Some say it's better, I don't know about that..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`transmission` and `deluge`'s console interfaces support this natively, there are also patches for `libtorrent`/`rtorrent` to provide magnet support (as shown [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-compile-rtorrent-from-svn-in-ubuntu-9.10-karmic-koala-debian-5-lenny-with-magnet-link-support)).

Answer (score 13):

aria2c supports magnet links, you could install it by:

```
# apt-get install aria2 
# aria2c -help
Usage: aria2c [OPTIONS] [URI | MAGNET | TORRENT_FILE | METALINK_FILE]...
Printing options whose name includes 'elp'.
Options:
....
```

(apt-get is a debianism)